# How to get and add execution time in second/minutes/.. in Zsh?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I'm using `zsh` and `Oh-my-zsh` and cobolt2 theme.
and use this bash code to see the date and time:

```
RPROMPT="%F{green}[%D{%a %f/%m/%y %b} | %D{%L:%M:%S}]"
```

[image]

and found this script to calculate execution time for each command:

```
function preexec() {
 timer=$(date +%s%3N)
}

function precmd() {
if [ $timer ]; then
local now=$(date +%s%3N)
local d_ms=$(($now-$timer))
local d_s=$((d_ms / 1000))
local ms=$((d_ms % 1000))
local s=$((d_s % 60))
local m=$(((d_s / 60) % 60))
local h=$((d_s / 3600))
if ((h > 0)); then elapsed=${h}h${m}m
elif ((m > 0)); then elapsed=${m}m${s}s
elif ((s >= 10)); then elapsed=${s}.$((ms / 100))s
elif ((s > 0)); then elapsed=${s}.$((ms / 10))s
else elapsed=${ms}ms
fi

export RPROMPT="%F{cyan}${elapsed} %{$reset_color%}"
unset timer
fi
}
```

how can I combine this to code and have took time at left side with another background color to be easy to read?

Comment: Are you using bash or zsh? These shells are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Well its a built-in feature, you can configure oh-my-zsh to get that

Make sure you are running zsh shell by typing

```
exec zsh
```

then run `p10k configure` in the same session

You will get an option to set the time granularity, in the configuration wizard

Example:
[image]

Comment: thanks, but I want to use it in cobalt2 because the p10k setting is so complicated and i don't like it